# Ruby Regex: Capture the same capture groups multiple times

Tags: regex, ruby

I've got these strings in our authentication system, and I'm trying to develop the right REGEX to capture specific information from them.

```
STRING = CR*reduced*downsized*U*reduced*D*own_only
```

Now I need to be able to extract the capital Letter (like CRUD) in the first capture group, plus the immediately following 'attributes' embraced by stars (e.g. *downsized*). That works quite fine for most cases with the following REGEX

```
(C)\*?([a-z_]+)?\*?    --> Capture Group 1: "C", Capture Group2: empty
(U)\*?([a-z_]+)?\*?    --> Capture Group 1: "U", Capture Group2: 'reduced'
(C)\*?([a-z_]+)?\*?    --> Capture Group 1: "D", Capture Group2: 'own_only'
```

For R, I would need both attributes returned, hence Capture Group2 should be 'reduced'  and Capture Group3 'downsized'. But with the same REGEX, I only get the following result

```
(R)\*?([a-z_]+)?\*?    --> Capture Group 1: "R", Capture Group2: 'reduced'
```

Any recommendation regarding Regex?

Comment: I modified my answer somewhat (adding an option of creating a hash), though it seems unlikely you are still concerned with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to extract the desired information is as follows.

```
def breakup(str)
  str.scan(/[A-Z][a-z_*]*/).map { |s| [s[0], s.scan(/[a-z_]+/)]}
end
```

The respective regular expressions read, "match an uppercase letter followed by zero or more (the final '*') lowercases letters, underscores and asterisks" and "match one or more (the '+') lowercase letters and underscores".

---

```
str1 = "CR*reduced*downsized*U*reduced*D*own_only"
breakup(str1)
  #=> [["C", []], ["R", ["reduced", "downsized"]], ["U", ["reduced"]],
  #    ["D", ["own_only"]]]
```

```
str2 = "CR*reduced*downsized*U*reduced*DE"    
breakup(str2)
  #=> [["C", []], ["R", ["reduced", "downsized"]], ["U", ["reduced"]],
  #    ["D", []], ["E", []]]
```

Note that

```
str1.scan(/[A-Z][a-z_*]*/)
  #=> ["C", "R*reduced*downsized*", "U*reduced*", "D*own_only"]
```

---

It may be more more useful to create a hash of matches:

```
def hashify(str)
  str.gsub(/[A-Z][a-z_*]*/).with_object({}) do |s,h|
    h[s[0]] = s.scan(/[a-z_]+/)
  end
end
```

```
hashify str1
  #=> {"C"=>[], "R"=>["reduced", "downsized"],
  #    "U"=>["reduced"], "D"=>["own_only"]}
```

```
hashify str2
  #=> {"C"=>[], "R"=>["reduced", "downsized"],
  #    "U"=>["reduced"], "D"=>[], "E"=>[]}
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a single argument and no block, and therefore returns an enumerator (that is chained to [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object)). Note that this form of `gsub` has nothing to do with string substitution; it merely enumerates matches of the given pattern, and when the given pattern is a regular  expression (as here), capture groups have no special significance (as they do with [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-scan)).

In fact, `scan` could be replaced with `gsub` in the definition of `breakup`. That would actually be preferable as it would avoid the construction of the intermediate array `str.scan(/[A-Z][a-z_*]*/)`.

---

Should it be necessary to test if the string has a valid construction one could attempt to match it against the following regular expression (which I've expressed in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting).

```
RGX =
  /
  \A              # match beginning of the string
  (?:             # begin a non-capture group
    [A-Z]         # match one upcase letter
    (?:           # begin a non-capture group
      (?:         # begin a non-capture group
        \*        # match '*'
        [a-z_]+   # match one or more of the characters indicated
      )+          # end non-capture group and execute one or more times 
      (?:         # begin a non-capture group
        \*        # match '*'
        (?=[A-Z]) # pos lookahead asserts next char is an upcase letter
        |         # or     
        \z        # at end of string
      )           # end non-capture group
    )?            # end non-capture group and optionally match it
  )+              # end non-capture group and execute it one or more times
  \z              # match end of string
  /x              # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

---

```
str3 = "CR*reduced*downsizedU*reduced*D*own_only"
str4 = "CR*reduced*downsized*U*reduced*D*own_only*"
str5 = "*CR*reduced*downsized*U*reduced*D*own_only"

[str1, str2, str3, str4, str5].map { |s| valid?(s) }
  #=> [true, true, false, false, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a scenario involving [repeated capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), you can use a multiple step solution like

```rb
text = 'CR*reduced*downsized*U*reduced*D*own_only'
rx = /([CRUD])((?:\*[a-z_]+(?:\*[a-z_]+)*(?:\*|$))?)/
matches = text.scan(rx)
p matches.map { |x| [x[0], x[1].split("*").reject(&:empty?)]};
# => [["C", []], ["R", ["reduced", "downsized"]], ["U", ["reduced"]], ["D", ["own_only"]]]
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/tX8Bhr) and the [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/EP6F0VPw0rSWYe).

*Details*:

- `([CRUD])` - Group 1: one of the 4 letters
- `((?:\*[a-z_]+(?:\*[a-z_]+)*(?:\*|$))?)` - Group 2: an optional sequence of

  - `\*` - a `*` char
  - `[a-z_]+` - one or more ASCII lowercase letters or underscores
  - `(?:\*[a-z_]+)*` - zero or more sequences of `*` and one or more ASCII lowercase letters or underscores
  - `(?:\*|$)` - `*` or end of a line (use `\z` to match end of whole string).

With `.map { |x| [x[0], x[1].split("*").reject(&:empty?)]}`, you can split the second group value with `*` and remove empty items.

Comment: But basically very short like this would also work ([CRUD])\*?([a-z_*]*). And is probably more CPU power efficient. I hoped to have gotten a single REGEX, but probbly I will go for multipstep apporach.

Comment: @fydelio Single regex is not possible in Ruby. In Python, C#, yes.